# php generate image from excel cell range

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel sheet. Its Cells can contain data and graph. I need to generate an image from the cells between a fixed range(for example: A1 to K19).

I found one solution to this problem with ASP.NET: [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx). It provides method [Range.CopyPicture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.copypicture.aspx) and [Chart.Paste()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.paste.aspx). I need to implement this using PHP. Any solution, suggestion or direction will be appreciated.

For range A1 to B2, image can be like :  [image: A1:B2]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721549/php-creating-image-from-html-table

Comment: I have been able to create image from text. but this option is not useful in case of excel.

Comment: can someone suggest down vote reason?

Comment: I have been able to do this using asp .net Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: I would assume the vote-down reason is because you're asking for code without trying anything first.

Comment: By modifying the question, I have tried to include all my research efforts so far. Someone please remove the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It can read xls and xlsx files; after reading them you are able to create images from text just like you did before.